# Compare two 64 bit variables on 32 bit microcontroller

Tags: c, int, 32-bit

I have the following issue: I have two 64 bit variables and they have to be compared as quick as possible, my Microcontroller is only 32bit.

My thoughts are that it is necessary to divide 64 bit variable into two 32 bit variables, like this

```
uint64_t var = 0xAAFFFFFFABCDELL;
hiPart = (uint32_t)((var & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000LL) >> 32);
loPart = (uint32_t)(var & 0xFFFFFFFFLL);
```

and then to compare hiParts and loParts, but I am sure that this approach is slow and there is much better solution

Comment: I think there is no completely different concept to do this since you still need to compare every bit if they are equal. However, you might be able to improve your comparison by comparing the high part first. If the high part differs the low part doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Your compiler allows for bitwise and, and shifting of 64-bit values but not `==` or other comparison operators?

Comment: If the compiler supports `uint64_t`, then the compiler can compare two variables of type `uint64_t`. All you need to do is `if (var1 == var2)`

Comment: Just in case a compiler wouldn't remove it anyway, there is no need to do the bitwise AND on the high part. Shifting right an unsigned value clears the upper bits. Also casting to 32bits will drop them anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The first rule should be: *Write your program, so that is readable to a human*.

When in doubt, don't assume anything, but measure it. Let's see, what [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eJLi5L) gives us.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool foo(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    return a == b;
}

bool foo2(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {

    uint32_t ahiPart = (uint32_t)((a & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) >> 32);
    uint32_t aloPart = (uint32_t)(a & 0xFFFFFFFFULL);
    uint32_t bhiPart = (uint32_t)((b & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) >> 32);
    uint32_t bloPart = (uint32_t)(b & 0xFFFFFFFFULL);

    return ahiPart == bhiPart && aloPart == bloPart;
}
```

```
foo:
        eor     r1, r1, r3
        eor     r0, r0, r2
        orr     r0, r0, r1
        rsbs    r1, r0, #0
        adc     r0, r0, r1
        bx      lr

foo2:
        eor     r1, r1, r3
        eor     r0, r0, r2
        orr     r0, r0, r1
        rsbs    r1, r0, #0
        adc     r0, r0, r1
        bx      lr
```

As you can see, they result in the exact same assembly code, but you decide, which one is less error prone and easiert to read?

Answer (score 1):

There was a time some years ago where you need to do tricks to be more smart than a compiler. But in 99.999% the compiler will be more smart than you.

And your variables are unsigned. So use `ULL` instead of `LL`.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to let the compiler do it. Most compilers are much better than humans at micro-optimization.

```
uint64_t var = …, other_var = …;
if (var == other_var) …
```

There aren't many ways to go about it. Under the hood, the compiler will arrange to load the upper 32 bits and the lower 32 bits of each variables into registers, and compare the two registers that contain upper 32 bits and the two registers that contain lower 32 bits. The assembly code might look something like this:

```
load 32 bits from &var into r0
load 32 bits from &other_var into r1
if r0 != r1: goto different
load 32 bits from &var + 4 into r2
load 32 bits from &other_var + 4 into r3
if r2 != r3: goto different
// code for if-equal
different:
// code for if-not-equal
```

Here are some things the compiler knows better than you:

- Which registers to use, based on the needs of the surrounding code.
- Whether to reuse the same registers to compare the upper and lower parts, or to use different registers.
- Whether to process one part and then the other (as above), or to load one variable then the other. The best order depends on the pressure on registers and on the memory access times and pipelining of the particular processor model.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with a union you could compare Hi and Lo Part without any extra calculations:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {    
        uint32_t   loPart;
        uint32_t   hiPart;
    };
    uint64_t       complete;
}uint64T;

uint64T var.complete = 0xAAFFFFFFABCDEULL;
```

Comment: While this would work for comparing only, be aware that accessing the *"lo"* and *"hi"* part is endianess dependent.

Comment: Yes of course. Put the comparing of two 64 Bit values will be fast.